# What can cause the squeak sound in the front right when driving faster then 70 km/h

Tags: toyota, suspension, steering

I just have bought a Toyota Yaris of 2007 and observe two things. There is a squeaking sound from right front when driving over 60-70 km/h. Another is when turning wheels right or left completely I hear creak (like a rubber by rubber) from both front wheels. Visually everything looks fine.

What can cause such noise and what can it cost me?

**Update**

So, the steering creak problem is solved. These were rubber hobs (the big rubber pieces where shock dampers connect to the body). We just put some oil there and after a few kilometers the sound disappeared.

Still looking for the solution of the other problem.

Comment: I might also add that a rock in the disc brake or worn brake pads may also cause squeaking near the wheel (even when not applying the brake).

Comment: I do not think this is a rock. The sound is in phase with the car swinging while driving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rubber to rubber sound may be from the tires rubbing on the frame. This is more likely if the wheels and tires are not the stock size. Crank the wheels to the left until it stops. Look into the wheel well and see if you can see black marks on the frame. Do the same on the right side. Place both hands on the right front fender and push down several times. Try to get it to bounce up and down while listening for the noise. This will isolate it to a suspension noise or a steering noise. As far as what could cause the noise, the list is large. Any pivot point in the suspension or steering linkage can squeek. Because the suspension and steering are so important this is not something you want to ignore.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The rubber sound appears even if I stand still and just turn the wheels. Some people say that it can be one of the rubber hobs in the suspension. I definitely need to check the suspension.